# Android - cannot find library, installing through the Play Store

Tags: android, android-ndk

I distributed the app to Play Store.

If I manually install the apk, it works normally.
However, if I proceed with the installation on the Play Store, it doesn't work.

error is

> "/data/app/ package-name  /lib/arm64/ mylib .so" no such file or directory

Here's how I tried to solve the problem.

`extractNativeLibs="true"` set on mainfest

`include("x86", "x86_64", "armeabi-v7a", "arm64-v8a")` set on build.gradle

Check if the library is saved normally.

`jni/CPU_ABI inside an AAR`

`lib/CPU_ABI inside the final APK`

It works normally in the installation except for the Play Store.
An error occurs only when installed through the Play Store.

I checked the existence of the library through the following instructions.

`ls /data/app/<package-nam>/lib/<system-abi>/`

If there's anything I forgot, the apk should not be installed manually. I don't know why an error occurs only when installing through the Play Store.